# Bundling CSS and JS using webpack with one config

Tags: javascript, wordpress, webpack

I'm trying to understand how webpack works. I'm developing a Wordpress theme and I decided to give Webpack a try.

I'm struggling with configuration for Webpack. Configuring it for handling SASS was fairly easy, but when it came to adding support for JS files that should be bundled into one JS file: `scripts.js`, then it became too difficult to understand how it works.

That's my config:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    watch: true,
    entry: ['./scss/style.scss'],
    output: {
        filename: './style.css',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({ // define where to save the file
            filename: './style.css',
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new UglifyJSPlugin({
            sourceMap: true
        })
    ]
};
```

I'm wondering how the configuration for JS files should look like?

Comment: Your entry point should be a javascript file, not a scss file. You can import scss files in your javascript file for webpack to find them. maybe suggested reading: http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/

Comment: @andy-ray I thought Webpack is a new approach for bundling things like Gulp or Grunt did before. Where I was adding a config for each plugin and I was receiving what I wanted.

Comment: Grunt and Gulp only work with files, and don't have a concept of a dependency graph. Webpack gives you a dependency graph for all of your static assets. In the most common setup, you require scss from your javascript code to tell Webpack your javascript app needs certain CSS to run

Comment: I see, but Wordpress template is not a JS app. It uses PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the webpack options:

```
entry: ['./scss/style.scss'],
output: {
    filename: './style.css',
    publicPath: '/'
},
```

with

```
entry: ['./js/index.js'],
output: {
    filename: './bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
},
```

The content of `./js/index.js`:

```
require('./scss/style.scss')
```

The output path of `style.css` bundle is specified alredy in your webpack config in options of `ExtractTextPlugin`. Include that `css` bundle like you generally do in html file.